# Get .NET Core DLL version on Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core

I have a .NET Core app which sets metadata properties during build, using standard options in the .csproj:

```xml
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>

    <Product>MyCoolProduct</Product> 
    <Version>0.1.1</Version>

  </PropertyGroup>

  <snip />

</Project>
```

On Windows, this is easy enough to retrieve from the compiled .dll either in Explorer, or via a PowerShell script. How can I do something similar on Linux? Ideally, I'd like to be able run a simple command like `dotnet inspect my.dll` and get a summary of metadata for that assembly, but what's the next best thing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use `exiftool`:

```
$ exiftool /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/Microsoft/Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions/tools/netcoreapp1.0/System.Threading.dll | grep -i version
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.55
Linker Version                  : 48.0
OS Version                      : 4.0
Image Version                   : 0.0
Subsystem Version               : 4.0
File Version Number             : 4.6.24705.1
Product Version Number          : 0.0.0.0
File Version                    : 4.6.24705.01
Product Version                 : 4.6.24705.01. Commit Hash: 4d1af962ca0fede10beb01d197367c2f90e92c97
Assembly Version                : 4.0.12.0
```

Originally discovered from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86147/viewing-dll-and-exe-file-properties-attributes-via-the-command-line).

Watch out, though. It doesn't work on `crossgen`ed stuff:

```
$ exiftool /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/Roslyn/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.55
File Name                       : Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll
Directory                       : /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/Roslyn
File Size                       : 4.6 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:01:24 13:12:48-05:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2018:02:01 12:37:59-05:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:01:26 09:52:23-05:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
Error                           : File format error
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `crossgen` issue? I'm seeing this work when I build manually (`dotnet build`) but fail when the .dlls are built by a `dockerfile`, guessing it has something to do with that?

Comment: I doubt it. [crossgen](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/crossgen.md) is used to build dlls that are included with .NET Core itself. You can also use it, but it is a manual step in the build process. `docker` shouldn't create crossgen'ed stuff. But [the mono linker does](https://github.com/mono/linker/pull/192). Oh, and to elaborate, Windows wont show versions for those crossgen'ed files too. If Windows Explorer can show the version of a dll, `exiftool` should too.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'd not heard of `exiftool` before but it seems quite useful, although also an example of why you should not give your app too specific of a name :)

Answer (score 2):

Finding the version of a program in a pod
cat /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/Microsoft/Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions/tools/netcoreapp1.0/System.Threading.deps.json | grep System.Threading

If the deps.json file is availible just FYI