# How to get .Net Core dll version from command line on linux?

Tags: linux, .net-core

I'm trying to solve dll's version conflict in deployment environment but can't find any way to check the version of deployed .dll

Does anybody know how it can be done?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please add some more information (detailed problem description, logs) so that people can help you out.

Comment: Are you talking about daemon, you installed in linux by .service file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get .NET Core DLL version on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571641/get-net-core-dll-version-on-linux)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it'll help, but try to use this command:

```
strings <your-file.dll> -el
```

Comment: Does not help. What I need to see is the string such as `.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1` and that does not get printed with `strings -el`. It does get printed when I leave out the `-el`, though then I need to hunt in much longer output for it.